# Weird "is not abstract and does not override abstract method" error

Tags: java, maven, gwt, annotations

Don't get what's the error saying. I have implemented the methodes and return type is correct.

The epic Error:

```
[ERROR] /tmp/build_834873cb-62d2-4c62-9b4e-29df7d0af404/src/main/java/com
/project/server/SearchServiceImpl.java:[8,7] error: SearchServiceImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getListings(String,String) in SearchService
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_834873cb-62d2-4c62-9b4e-29df7d0af404/src/main/java/com
/project/server/SearchServiceImpl.java:[10,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

The SearchService interface:

```
    package com.project.client.rpcinterfaces;

    @RemoteServiceRelativePath("searchservice")
    public interface SearchService extends RemoteService{
        ArrayList<ListingInterface> getListings(String userName, String idHash);
}
```

The implementation:

```
@Service(value="searchservice")
public class SearchServiceImpl implements SearchService{
     @Autowired
 private ApplicationContext ctx;
     @Override
     public ArrayList<ListingInterface> getListings(String userName, String idHash) {

        UserItemsImpl userItems = ctx.getBean(UserItemsImpl.class);


        ArrayList<ListingInterface> listingsList = userItems.getListings(userName, idHash);


        return listingsList;
    }
}
```

The ListingInterface:

```
 public interface ListingInterface{

     public List<TermsSearchResultInterface> getSearchResults();

    /*
     * Returns the indexed search result
     */ 
     public TermsSearchResultInterface getSearchResult(int index);

     public String getTitle();

     public void setTitle(String title);

     public String[] getTags();

     public void setSearchResults(List<TermsSearchResultInterface> searchResults);

     public void setTags(String[] tags);

     public String getListingId();

     public void setListingId(String listingId);

     public List<String> getExcludedTerms();

     public void setExcludedTerms(List<String> excludedTerms);



}
```

Program runs correctly in Dev Mode. Only when i try to upload it to Heroku.com then maven starts to Error :)

Spent few hours on this. If you could give me pointers what's wrong would be big help, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was with git repository.That's why it worked in my local machine and not in server. I removed my test servers, .git and then uploaded it again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Extend your `SearchServiceImpl` with this class `RemoteServiceServlet`

```
public class SearchServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements SearchService{
.
.
.
}
```

Also check if your web.xml has appropriate servlet and servlet-mapping

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SearchServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>...path.....SearchServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>searchServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yourPattern</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I'm trying to `--force` with git. Maybe that has an impact, because I can install it with maven nicely to my home server..